# MySQL join strange results

Tags: mysql, join

Can anyone help, mysql is beyond me I think!

I have the following tables:

- matches
- teams
- competition

matches holds the details of a game between two teams and the corresponding competition.

I want to query the data base for all games/fixtures for a given competition, I want to return:

- team names
- team id
- team competition

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
  matches.match_id,
  teamsh.team_name AS "homeTeam",
  teamsa.team_name AS "awayTeam",
  competition.competition_id,
  competition.name
FROM
  matches, teams teamsh, teams teamsa, competition
WHERE
  matches.home_team_id = teamsh.team_id
AND matches.away_team_id = teamsa.team_id
AND matches.competition_id=2
```

For some reason this query returns all fixtures correctly for competition 2, but then it also returns rows for the fixture but as competition 1 also. I can't understand why as I have the clause:

```
AND matches.competition_id=2
```

What am I doing wrong, I have checked the database and the matches are stored correctly for each fixture.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't explicitly linked to the competition table (so it's performing a cartesian join) - try adding:

```
and matches.competition_id = competition.competition_id
```

- to the end of your query.

Although, I would suggest rewriting the query to use the explicit join syntax - like so:

```
SELECT m.match_id,
       h.team_name AS "homeTeam",
       a.team_name AS "awayTeam",
       c.competition_id,
       c.name
FROM matches m
JOIN teams h ON m.home_team_id = h.team_id
JOIN teams a ON m.away_team_id = a.team_id
JOIN competition c ON m.competition_id = c.competition_id
WHERE m.competition_id=2
```

Comment: Thnaks that worked perfectly. Cartesian join is a term I have not heard for about 10 years since I was back in college, I need to go back and read up on this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `JOIN` condition between the competitions and matches tables.

```
WHERE
  matches.home_team_id = teamsh.team_id
  AND matches.away_team_id = teamsa.team_id
  AND matches.competition_id = competition.competition_id
  AND matches.competition_id=2
```